# Listview backcolor or forecolor based on cell value

Tags: vb.net

Is there a better way to change the entire row color?

```
For i = 2 To LRow
Set LstItem = UserForm1.lstInvoiceItems.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngdata.Cells(i, 1).Value)
For j = 2 To ColCount
    LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngdata.Cells(i, j).Value
Next j
If rngdata.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
    LstItem.ForeColor = vbRed
    LstItem.ListSubItems.Item(1).ForeColor = vbRed
    LstItem.ListSubItems.Item(2).ForeColor = vbRed
    LstItem.ListSubItems.Item(3).ForeColor = vbRed
    LstItem.ListSubItems.Item(4).ForeColor = vbRed
    LstItem.ListSubItems.Item(5).ForeColor = vbRed
    LstItem.ListSubItems.Item(6).ForeColor = vbRed
    LstItem.ListSubItems.Item(7).ForeColor = vbRed
End if
Next i
```

Comment: Well you could loop through the subitems in order to reduce repetitive code

Comment: @ADyson Thank you! no other way to change the color of entire row at one go?

Comment: Not that I know of. But I'm not a Windows forms expert. You could see whether the main list item (rather than the sub items) has a color property which controls the whole row. I don't know. The Microsoft documentation for a list view item will show you all the properties. Or intellisense in visual studio will tell you.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.useitemstyleforsubitems?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ADyson n Andrew, Thank you for your time and inputs.

Comment: Also look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.forecolor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ListViewItem_ForeColor . That's the documentation I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edited version to work with a listview.  I've subbed it off with the intention that you can just call it after your data is all populated - or after your data is updated/added to/edited.  It'll loop through your whole listview and color the entire row based on either the first cell value or a subitem (see commented out If line)

For the actual color coding you want to look at the item not each sub item - if you change the forecolor on the parent item all of it's children will inherit the same setting

```
    Private Sub ColorCode()
    For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1 'you don't want it looking at the blank last line
        If ListView1.Items(i).Text = 123 Then 'Change this to whatever critera you need to color code
            'If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text = 5 Then 'Alternatively if you want to go by your sub item for criteria
            ListView1.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Original Answer below:

I'm not 100% sure if you can tweak this to work with a listview but if you can change your control to a datagridview you can use the following code:

```
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = "" Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = vbRed
        End If
    Next
```

Depending on what your application is doing I'd suggest using a datagridview over the listview

Comment: Thank you... but my coding is done using listview. In my next project will try using DataGridView. Thanks for your time and inputs.

Comment: After adding all your data you could add in a function and run it afterwards and just color code the listview itself instead of trying to color the items one by one


something more like:

    ListView1.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = Color.Red

in a for loop with an if statement around it

Comment: I updated the answer with a way to achieve this for a listview

Comment: Thank you! Yes Adyson has stated the similar solution. Thank you!